# import CSV in another language to SAS

Tags: csv, sas

I am attempting to import a CSV file which is in French to my US based analysis. I have noticed several issues in the import related to the use of accents. I put the csv file into a text reader and found that the data look like this

[image: example from text file]

I am unsure how to get rid of the [sub] pieces and format this properly.

I am on SAS 9.3 and am unable to edit the CSV as it is a shared CSV with French researchers. I am also limited to what I can do in terms of additional languages within SAS because of admin rights.

I have tried the following fixes:

```
data want(encoding=asciiany);
set have;
comment= Compress(comment,'0D0A'x);
comment= TRANWRD(comment,'0D0A'x,'');
comment= TRANWRD(comment,'0D'x,'');
comment= TRANWRD(comment,"\u001a",'');
```

How can I resolve these issues?

Comment: A CSV file has no language. It's just a text file with fields separated by a specific delimiter, most often a comma. The is trying to a UTF8 file using the wrong codepage `asciiany`. Just remove it. You won't be able to read even English text with just the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage. Names like `Brontë` will be mangled

Comment: Using asciiany was my last attempt. Previously I had nothing specified and the error in the import presisted.

Comment: You have a UTF8 file. Use the correct encoding. As for `the last attempt`, that codepage is always wrong. In the byte range `0x00-0x7F` UTF8 and US-ASCII are identical by design. Characters above that range use 2 bytes. When your code tried to read the UTF8 file the upper byte couldn't be translated and was replaced by `SUB`

Comment: Have you tried UTF8? BTW almost all web pages are UTF8, including StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I have never heard of a UTF8 file (I'm a stats researcher with no background in computer science or IT) and am not sure how to find the correct encoding.

Comment: Have you tried using `UTF8` or `UTF-8` instead of `asciiany`? As for text encodings, [check the Wikipedia UTF8 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). UTF8 is used by every web page and most desktop applications.

Comment: I have changed the data step to data want(encoding=UTF8); just in case that is what you mean and it did not solve the issue. The [sub]s remain in the SAS upload from the CSV

Comment: I'm confused about talking about webpages since I'm using SAS 9.3 (not the web based version) and uploading a CSV. I'm not sure how a webpage relates.

Comment: What encoding is your SAS session using? Check the ENCODING system option.  What actual bytes are in the file at those positions? Read the file as binary and use the LIST statement to see. For example to see the first 1,000 bytes use  `data _null_; infile 'myfile.csv' lrecl=100 recfm=f obs=10; input; list; run;`

Comment: @Tom Here is what I get: NOTE: A byte-order mark in the file "myfile.csv" (for fileref "#LN00135")
      indicates that the data is encoded in "utf-8".  This encoding will be used to process the file.  and when I look up the encoding I found this ENCODING=WLATIN1  Specifies the default character-set encoding for the SAS session.

Comment: In which case some of the UTF-8 characters in the file are not included in the 256 characters that WLATIN1 can represent. So run a new SAS session that is using ENCODING='UTF-8' and you will be able to read all of the strange characters in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
data want;
  array f[8] $4 _temporary_ ('ä'  'ö'  'ü'  'ß'  'Ä'  'Ö'  'Ü'  'É');
  array t[8] $4 _temporary_ ('ae' 'oe' 'ue' 'ss' 'Ae' 'Oe' 'Ue' 'E');
  set have;
  newvar=oldvar;

newvar = Compress(newvar,'0D0A'x);
newvar = TRANWRD(newvar,'0D0A'x,'');
newvar = TRANWRD(newvar,'0D'x,'');
newvar = TRANWRD(newvar,"\u001a",'');
newvar = compress(newvar, , 'kw');
  do _n_=1 to dim(f);
    d=tranwrd(d, trim(f[_n_]), trim(t[_n_]));
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

While this would have been a major issue a few decades ago, nowadays, it's very simple to determine the encoding and then run your SAS in the right mode.

First, open the CSV in a text editor, not the basic Notepad but almost any other; Notepad++ is free, for example, or Ultraedit or Textpad, on Windows, or on the Mac, BBEdit, or several others will do.  I'll assume Notepad++ for the rest of this answer, but all of them have some way of doing this.  If you're in a restricted no-admin-rights environment, good news: Notepad++ can be installed in your user folder with no admin rights (or even on a USB!). (Also, an advanced text editor is a vital data science tool, so you should have one anyway.)

In Notepad++, once you open the file there will be an encoding in the bottom right: "UTF-8", "WLATIN1", "ASCII", etc., depending on the encoding of the file.  Look and see what that is, and write it down.

Once you have that, you can try starting SAS in that encoding.  For the rest of this, I assume it is in UTF-8 as that is fairly standard, but replace UTF-8 with whatever the encoding you determined. earlier.

See [this article](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/movefile/n06qan4j3ffr6fn11bs4q11r8r56.htm#n01964oa2but8wn1kkfk95adhlfj) for more details; the instructions are for 9.4, but they have been the same for years.  If this doesn't work, you'll need to talk to your SAS administrator, and they may need to modify your SAS installation.

You can either:

- Make a new shortcut (a copy of the one you run SAS with) and add `-encoding UTF-8` to the command line
- Create a new configuration file, point SAS to it, and include `ENCODING=UTF-8` in the configuration file.

Note that this will have some other impacts - the datasets you create will be encoded in UTF-8, and while SAS is capable of handling that, it will add some extra notes to the log and some extra time if you later do work in non-UTF8 SAS with this, or if you use non-UTF8 SAS datasets in this mode.